# Add customers next returned date from R data set

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with date and customer name. I am looking to add a returned date which is the next time a customer returns to my data set. What is the easiest way to do this in R? If the customer has not returned yet then the result should be blank.

```
Date <-seq(as.Date('2017/01/01'), as.Date('2017/01/9'), by="day")
Cust <- c("A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C")
df1 <- data.frame(Date,Cust)

    Date    Cust
1   01/01/17    A
2   02/01/17    B
3   03/01/17    C
4   04/01/17    A
5   05/01/17    B
6   06/01/17    C
7   07/01/17    A
8   08/01/17    B
9   09/01/17    C
```

Expected result

```
    Date    Cust    returnedDate
1   01/01/17    A   04/01/17
2   02/01/17    B   05/01/17
3   03/01/17    C   06/01/17
4   04/01/17    A   07/01/17
5   05/01/17    B   08/01/17
6   06/01/17    C   09/01/17
7   07/01/17    A   NA
8   08/01/17    B   NA
9   09/01/17    C   NA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this using a group by `shift` operation in `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'Cust', get the lead values of 'Date' and assign (`:=`) as 'returnDate'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, returnDate := shift(Date, type = "lead"), Cust]
df1
#         Date Cust returnDate
#1: 2017-01-01    A 2017-01-04
#2: 2017-01-02    B 2017-01-05
#3: 2017-01-03    C 2017-01-06
#4: 2017-01-04    A 2017-01-07
#5: 2017-01-05    B 2017-01-08
#6: 2017-01-06    C 2017-01-09
#7: 2017-01-07    A       <NA>
#8: 2017-01-08    B       <NA>
#9: 2017-01-09    C       <NA>
```

NOTE: If the OP wanted the 'Date's to be in a certain format, use the `format`

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you!!